# Assigning role to interactive elements via constant

Tags: javascript, html, eslint

I have one actionable `div` as follows

```
const ROLE = 'button';
<div tabIndex={0} role={ROLE} onClick{actionHandler} onKeyPress={actionHandler}/>
```

The eslint still throws and error `no-static-element-interactions`. But if the role is directly assigned i.e without using constant it works

```
role="button"
```

Is there any way in which role can be assigned via constants.